# How to display release notes before installation in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to be able to display the release notes to the end user before the installation has started (e.g. if there are any code changes they should be aware of before upgrading to a newer version).

I've read the documentation regarding the Pascal code  [BeforeInstall and AfterInstall Parameters](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall), but my problem is how can I make a reference to my release notes file as it is packed inside the setup executable? I realise the simplest answer would be to simply package the installer with a copy of the text file sitting alongside it so it could reference it in this way, but then if the user only copies the executable for example, this would presumably cause a reference error.

What is the best way to go about implementing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the [`InfoBeforeFile` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_infobeforefile):

```
[Setup]
InfoBeforeFile=infobefore.txt
```

---

[image]